# ¿Cómo obtengo la cantidad de hashes dentro de un array?

Tags: ruby

Tengo un programa que registra los datos de una persona. Creé el *array* `personas = []`, vacío para que cuando el usuario se registre, éste almacene un nuevo *hash* con sus datos dentro del *array* `personas`, así on `gets.chomp` se van obteniendo los datos uno por uno; ejemplo:

```
a = gets.chomp
persona = { nombre:a, edad:b, comuna:c, género:d }
personas.push(persona)
```

La cosa es que deseo mostrar la cantidad de personas registradas en mis otras opciones para el cliente. La pregunta es, **¿cómo convierto o muestro la cantidad de *hashes* en un número entero?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que cada persona (hash) es un elemento dentro del arreglo `personas`, sólo tienes que mostrar el tamaño del arreglo, lo cual puedes lograr con el método [Array#size](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-size):

```
personas = []
a = gets.chomp
persona = { nombre:a, edad:b, comuna:c, género:d }
personas.push(persona) 

personas.size
#=> 1
```